# How to fix different browsers changing my div width?

Tags: html, css, menu, cross-browser

This is normally a question I don't need answered, however, I am baffled. I have tried everything I can think of.
This picture includes a gray piece at the right. That is the scroll bar, figured I would include it. This is on Google Chrome and how I want it.

[image]

And this is how Microsoft Edge does it.
[image]

I narrowed the problem down to my list items `<li>`. On Google Chrome (according to my resolutions), the width of `<li>` is 226.141px and on Microsoft Edge, using the same exact CSS, the width of `<li>` is 226.35px.

Here is my style.css:

```
div.menuContainer {
width:100%;
height:48px;
}

ul.menuItems {
/*margin:-12px;*/
}

li.menuItem {
display:inline-block;
box-sizing:border-box;
width:calc(100% / 7);
float:left;
text-align:center;
height:48px;
font-weight:bold;
background-color:#DD4400;
color:#454545;
padding:12px 0;
overflow:hidden !important;
}

li.menuItem:hover {
background-color:#454545;
color:#DD4400;
}

li.menuItem a {
color:#454545;
}

li.menuItem a:hover {
color:#DD4400;
}
```

Here is my menu:

```
<div class="menuContainer">

<ul class="menuItems">
    <a href="/videos.php">
    <li class="menuItem">
    Videos
    </li>
    </a>

    <a href="/playlists.php">
    <li class="menuItem">
    Playlists
    </li>
    </a>

    <a href="/categories.php">
    <li class="menuItem">
    Categories
    </li>
    </a>

    <a href="/actors.php">
    <li class="menuItem">
    Actors
    </li>
    </a>

    <a href="/photos.php">
    <li class="menuItem">
    Photos
    </li>
    </a>

    <?php if($logged_in == 0) { ?>
    <a href="/login.php">
    <li class="menuItem">
    Login
    </li>
    </a>

    <a href="/register.php">
    <li class="menuItem">
    Register
    </li>
    </a>
    <?php } 

    else { ?>

    <a href="/logout.php">
    <li class="menuItem">
    Logout
    </li>
    </a>

    <a href="/account.php">
    <li class="menuItem">
    My Account
    </li>
    </a>

    <?php }

    ?>
</ul>

</div>
```

Any help you can provide would be greatly appreciated. Thank You.

Comment: which css reset do you use?

Comment: * { padding:0; margin:0; }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a different way of approaching the same problem using flexbox. I also made some slight modifications to your HTML. The key to this approach is using `display: flex` on the container and `flex-grow: 1` on the children of that container. Note: I also use `display: flex` to achieve vertical and horizontal centering on the `<a>` elements, rather than having to use top and bottom padding.

```css
.menu {
  height: 48px;
  display: flex;
}

.menu a {
  flex-grow: 1;
  display: flex;
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: #DD4400;
  color: #454545;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.menu a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
  <a href="/videos.php">Videos</a>
  <a href="/playlists.php">Playlists</a>
  <a href="/categories.php">Categories</a>
  <a href="/actors.php">Actors</a>
  <a href="/photos.php">Photos</a>
  <a href="/logout.php">Logout</a>
  <a href="/account.php">My Account</a>
</div>
```

Here's a quick article explaining what flexbox can do for you - [css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox). I'd highly recommend adding this to your toolkit - it's relatively modern, but has very good browser support [caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox). I use it very regularly.

Comment: I was always told to never put a link outside a div as I did. But I see how you made the whole box clickable by setting a 100% height to the link style. Another tool I'll add. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Sure thing. You may also find it easier to ditch the `ul` and `li` tags entirely (unless you need the semantic html for some reason). You could achieve the same results with a single `div` container with `a` children.

Comment: How I use to do it, was float:left all children divs until someone advised me to put them in a list. But that was a few years ago I started using the lists.

Comment: Here, I've updated the answer to simplify the HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Do a reset in your css, as a first thing:

```
* {
   /* So 100% means 100% */ 
   box-sizing: border-box; 
}
```

See [link](https://css-tricks.com/a-couple-of-use-cases-for-calc/) for details.

Comment: Yes, I have that. And padding:0; margin:0